# Angular2 - Not able to data bind when property is changed from different component (plunker example)

Tags: angular

I want to create an ErrorComponent responsible to display any error message for the entire application on the top of the page. So, naturally I was wondering about something like:

`<my-app>
    <error-app></error-app>
    <!-- Other stuff -->
</my-app>`

I have a Pluker website which illustrate the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/wYy4gl

I want to be able to add an error from anywhere calling the ErrorComponent. As in:

`// File app/app.component.ts
onSelect(hero: Hero) {
    this.selectedHero = hero; 
    this.errorComp.addError(hero.name);
}`

The alert shows the errors being added to `errors`: 

`// File app/error-app.component.ts
addError(e:string) {
    this.errors.push(e);
    alert("Errors:" + this.errors + "| AddeError: " + e);
}`

But the list `{{errors}}` is not being updated by some reason:

`// File app/error-app.component.ts
<li>{{errors}}</li>`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<li>{{errors}}</li>` try this:

```
<li *ngFor="let error of errors">{{error}}</li>
```

Also, you referenced your error component in the wrong way.
Instead of injecting it via DI you should use @ViewChild, like so:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

// ....

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [ ErrorAppComponent],
  //providers: [ErrorAppComponent ],
  template: `
    <h2>Error list</h2>
    <error-app #error></error-app>
    <hr>
    <h2>Click bellow to add to the error list</h2>
    <ul class="heroes">
      <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
        (click)="onSelect(hero)">
        <span class="badge"></span> {{hero.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() { }
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;
  @ViewChild("error") errorComp;

  onSelect(hero: Hero) {
    this.selectedHero = hero; 
    this.errorComp.addError(hero.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not solve the problem. The problem is related to the fact that the erros array is being updated but for some reason the DOM is not being updated.

Comment: It definitely needs the ngFor, otherwise the elements of your errors array won't show. Can you post the entire template of your error component?

Comment: Hi @hholtij, you can see the entire code on Plunker. I added your suggestion but still doen't work. Displaying the errors is not a problem. The problem is updating the errors after clicking on one of the options : http://plnkr.co/edit/wYy4gl?p=preview

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.